# How to load package version into __version__ variable if you are using pbr?

Tags: pip, setuptools, python-pbr

In order to simplify python packaging I am trying to migrate to use of pbr.

Still, I was not able to figure out how to expose the version of the package into `__version__` variable.

This is quite important because I do have many users of the package that do rely on the existence of the **version** variable.

People should be able to do:

```
import somemodule
print(somemodule.__version__)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if that's the best approach but I was able to spot one other packages that is doing something similar: [mock](https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock/blob/master/mock/mock.py).

```
__all__ = (
    '__version__',
    'version_info'
)

from pbr.version import VersionInfo

_v = VersionInfo('mock').semantic_version()
__version__ = _v.release_string()
version_info = _v.version_tuple()
```

Comment: I find it curious/frustrating that pbr doesn't need a dependency when in `setup.py` but when I try and use it in my command line script I have to list it in `requirements.txt`

Comment: @Lucas that is not really true that "pbr does not need dependency in setup.py" it actually is specified as setup dependency: `setup_requires=['pbr']`
But agree that this is not really clean solution...

Answer (score 3):

As the existing answer wasn't clear on some of the setup required, here is a reply with some more context.

### Update your version string

First, update your version string in your `setup.cfg`, if tracking it manually there.

Otherwise, if pulling version and other info from the git repo:

- make your new commit
- generate a new version tag (if not a development release)
- run `py setup.py sdist` to generate your distribution and update local files based on the git info (`AUTHORS`, ChangeLog, etc.).

**Note:** The quickest command to generate new version from updated Git tags is `python setup.py install`, but I've seen a warning not to use that. It's working fine for me, but may just be my particular setup.  Using the `sdist` or a `bdist_xxx` will generate a full distribution that you need to delete if you aren't using it.

### Setup package `__init__.py`

**my_package/**init**.py**

```py
all = ('__version__',)

from pbr.version import VersionInfo

# Check the PBR version module docs for other options than release_string()
__version__ = VersionInfo('<my_package>').release_string()
```

Then in the script using the package

**my_script.py**

```py
import my_package

print(my_package.__version__)
```

For more details, see the [`pbr.version` module documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/reference/api/pbr.html#module-pbr.version).

Comment: Shouldn't the first line in `__init__.py` be `__all__ = ('__version__',)`? 

Note the trailing comma to make the value a tuple, not a string.

Comment: @akaihola Yes, that looks right. Updated, but not tested - I've moved on to using the Poetry package with poetry-dynamic-versioning to manage version in Python repos.