# How can I use pbr version from source?

Tags: python, git, versioning, setuptools, python-pbr

**My goal:**

I want to keep coherent **versions** in my **GIT** repository, my distribution on **pypi** repository, and in my source using the **`__version__`** variable.

---

**Details:**

I tried to use **[pbr](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/3.0.0/)**, which generates the distro version from git tags, so these two versions will be coherent. However, I cannot find out how to keep the `__version__` variable coherent with them in my source. (There are [several ways](https://packaging.python.org/guides/single-sourcing-package-version/) to fetch the version from source, but how will it be connected to git/distro?)

Is it possible to generate a version file (to parse form source) or directly modify the `__version__` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2073599/2506522) post.

```py
import pkg_resources  # part of setuptools
version = pkg_resources.require("MyProject")[0].version
```

**UPDATE**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52740408/2506522) post shows another, more robust solution:

```py
from pbr.version import VersionInfo

package_name='MyProject'
info = VersionInfo(package_name)

version = info.version_string()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since *Python 3.8* there is a solution directly in the standard library: `__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('Example')`. See [Using importlib.metadata](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.metadata.html).