# How to update git metadata in a Python Packages using Setuptools and PBR

Tags: python, versioning, setuptools, python-pbr

### Working with versions generated from git repo tags by `pbr`

I'm having issues getting the version info from my package, which is setup as a normal Python package using `setuptools` with the `pbr` extension. `pbr` will pull the version info from the tags in a git repo so there is a single source of truth.

I did get the basics working - [see this Q&A for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58491577/python-setuptools-and-pbr-how-to-create-a-package-release-using-the-git-tag-as).

It *is* working overall, if I make a full distribution of the package.  For example: `py setup.py sdist` will create a full distribution and the version tag and other meta data from git is updated.

But I don't need full distributions of this package, my team is just working on it locally out of a git repo. I'm also using `pyinstaller` to create an executable of the main script for user distribution (without needing Python). So I want a simple, quick command that will just update the metadata, based on the latest updated to the git repo, without spending extra time for SetupTools to build and create the full distribution package, which will not be used anyway.

`pbr` will pull version (from tags), authors, and changelog info from the repo, so it's a big timesaver, allowing us to keep most of the metadata directly in git.

#### Questions

Is there anything we can do to get the package metadata to update with `pbr`, without making a full distribution?

Particularly on the version:

1. When or with which commands will `setup.py` using the `pbr` extension actually go update the version from the git repo so that any command querying the version will get the updated version?
2. Where is the version actually stored in this setup? (I can't find it...)

---

#### More info and some code

I've got a very short `setup.py`, for use with `pbr` extension:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup
setup(
    setup_requires=['pbr', 'setuptools'],
    pbr=True,
)
```

Now, if I update the latest commit in the git repo with a tag, the command `py setup.py --version` will return the new updated version based on that tag, but any other direct method I can find will still return the old version string. So that command does not appear to store the new version string anywhere.

Here's a few methods I've tried from my package `__init__.py`:

```py
import pkg_resources  # part of setuptools

v1 = pkg_resources.require("md2mat")[0].version
print('v1 {}'.format(v1))
v2 = pkg_resources.get_distribution('md2mat').version
print('v2 {}'.format(v2))

from pbr.version import VersionInfo

v3 = VersionInfo('md2mat').release_string()
print('v3 {}'.format(v3))

# Update per sinoroc's comment:
# As of Python 3.8, you can use this from the stdlib,
# which removes run-time dependencies on `pbr` or `setuptools`
import importlib.metadata

__version__ = importlib.metadata.version('Example')
```

All of the above return the **old** version string (last time a full distribution was made).

So, is there anything I can do short of `py setup.py sdist` or a similar full distribution build command (bdist, bdist_egg, etc.) to simply update my package info in place so the above methods will give me the latest version string and other git metadata when the main package script is run?

That would allow us to update the package locally as developers after checking out a new commit, and to then run `pyinstaller` to create our exe and release our end user version of the script.

Comment: I have to mention `import importlib.metadata; __version__ = importlib.metadata.version('Example')` since it's in the [standard library since Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html). It prevents from having run time dependencies (`install_requires`) on `setuptools` or `pbr`.

Comment: I saw that somewhere and tried it, but it didn't work. I am only on 3.7.4... probably worth updating to try this out. I still can't get the `pkg_resources` methods to work with `pyinstaller`... thanks for the tip.

Comment: There's a [backport called importlib-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/) to ease with the transition, but then it's just trading a dependency for another one.

Comment: FYI, I got `importlib-metadata` working with Python 3.8.0, but PyInstaller wouldn't successfully compile my package, so I'm back on Python 3.7.  I believe all the other information and steps are still required, so while this provides a cleaner method for accessing the metadata in scripts, it's only a nice-to-have for the moment, that I can't use at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the info for version is stored in the `package.egg-info/PKG-INFO` file.  Therefore, any `setuptools` command that updates the egg-info will pull in the git info.

In the `PKG-INFO` file, the Version is showing up for me currently in the 3rd line:

```
Version: 2.0.4.0b2
```

Updating the Version string directly in the PKG-INFO file does cause the scripts to display the updated string when accessing through `pkg_resources` or `pbr.version`.

The quickest command to have PBR automatically update the metadata in the .egg-info folder appears to be:

```py
py setup.py egg_info
```

longer / more complex commands that will also update the info include `build`, `sdist`, `bdist`, etc. See `py setup.py --help-commands` for more available `setup.py` commands.

---

#### Authors and Changelog

While the above is true for versioning, the `AUTHORS` and `ChangeLog` files DO NOT get updated by pbr for the `egg_info` or `build` commands.

However, these files are generated during the `sdist` and `bdist` commands (including all versions of `bdist`, I think). So it still looks like to update all the metadata from Git one of the full distribution build commands is required.

Commands that will **not** generate the AUTHORS and ChangeLog files:

```sh
py setup.py egg_info
py setup.py build
py setup.py develop
```

---

*(Note: I use the fairly recent `py` command to run python, which allows you to setup your default environment for running python, but you may need to use `python` or `python3` instead)*

Comment: Doesn't it work with `python3 setup.py develop`? If it does, then it seems to me that it's the one you should use, as it is closer to what you actually want to do. No need to build distributions.

Comment: I tried it and `develop` does run `egg_info` but doesn't update `AUTHORS` or `ChangeLog` (unfortunately).  I updated the answer. This feels like a good enhancement request for `pbr`...